# How do I make my custom cursor work in create-react-app?

Tags: css, reactjs, png, styling, web-frontend

I am using create-react-app, and have created a button. Within the (in line styling css) for this button, I've used cursor: "url(Pin.png), auto" but my cursor has not changed! I can change it into any other built-in cursor type (eg. pointer, auto, text, crosshair etc.) but when I try making it this png (and have tried svg as well) it does not work.

If I try simply rendering the png to the page it works fine. The png lives in my src directory with the rest of my js/jsx files, as does another png that is being displayed correctly as the background.

I've yarn installed resolve-url-loader and that hasn't helped either.

```
<div>
<button 

style={{cursor: "url(Pin.png), auto;", position: "absolute", 
top: "35%", right: "11%", height: "340px", width: "1010px", border: "0px", 
outline: "none", background: "transparent"}} 

onClick={this.openJoyModal}> 
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What about trying to import the png and then use it inside a template string? `import Pin from 'src/Pin.png';` then in your style `cursor: \`url(${Pin}), auto;\``.

Answer (score 0):

You should import it like @JulioBetta said in the comments `import Pin from 'src/Pin.png';`.

When loading a page in a browser, by default, React looks in the **public** directory and not the **src** when doing things like loading an image from `'Pin.png'` or `'assets/images/Pin.png'` unless the image, etc has been imported. Then the image needs to be in the proper **src** directory.